# How to resolve self signed certificate error while running capybara tests?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I am trying to run rspec /capybara tests on chrome browser. i am getting the error as shown in the screenshot[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jUbx.jpg)

my chrome version is 86 with matching chromedriver.
Following is my spec helper where i register my driver

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
        profile['extensions.password_manager_enabled'] = false
        caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
          "goog:chromeOptions" =>
          {
            "args" => [ "--start-maximized", "--test-type", "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-infobars" ],
            "prefs" => { "profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation" => 1, "profile.password_manager_enabled" => false, "credentials_enable_service" => false }
          },
          "unhandledPromptBehavior" => "ignore"
        )

        if !ENV.key?( "PARALLEL_TEST_GROUPS" )
           @driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client})
        else
           port =scan_port
           p "generated port:"+port.to_s
           @driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client, :port => port})
       
        end

      end
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly which connection the error is coming from, but assuming it's from the browser attempting to connect to your app, from https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ you can try the --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list command line option. Another option would be to add your self-signed CA to your machines allowed CAs thereby making the certs valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the webdrivers gem in my spec_helper file. i commented this and manually placed my chromedriverin my bin folder. i will debug further later as suggested Right now, i am hard pressed for time. i did try introducing a valid self signed certificate in my keychain which didnt work out